# Transaction RollBack when success

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, rollback

How to create a query that tests an "update command" and the same time rollback data?  Would be to have a feedback like: ALL RIGHT! Everything worked!  Note: Using SQL Transaction

Comment: Like, start a transaction, run the update, then rollback?  I don't understand the question.  What is it exactly you're looking for?

Comment: Like commit and rollback buttons on Oracle.  That only test to see if scripts works

Answer (score 2):

This should return a 1 if there's an error and ROLLBACK no matter the result:

```
DECLARE @ErrorCheck int
SET @ErrorCheck = 0

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --RUN UPDATE STATEMENT HERE
    IF (@@ERROR != 0)
        SET @ErrorCheck = 1

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

SELECT @ErrorCheck
```

Comment: All right! Its works with all commands too? I have a feedback? For example: 2 rows updated?

Comment: Try it out and verify the results are as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use transactions:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

 Update table1 set col1 = col1 + col2 where col3 = 'X'

 Select * from table1 where Col3 = 'X'

 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: All right! Its works with all commands too? I have a feedback? For example: 2 rows updated?